# MuleSoft AnypointStudio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have scripts:

```
<set-variable value="#[attributes.headers['Authorization']]" doc:name="apikey" doc:id="69f6509e-8c0c-4832-854e-d7c07675cb49" variableName="apiKey"/>
            <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="86d51474-a71e-438c-bb24-59471424c4f9" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration">
                <http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
    ---
    {
        Authorization : vars.apiKey
    }]]]></http:headers>
            </http:request>
```

and in the postman I have in Headers Key: Authorization and value the apiKey.

After call in Postman I have this message in AS:
HTTP GET on resource failed: bad request (400)

Why I have bad request?

Comment: Please provide more details of the issue, what you are doing, more details of the error and the HTTP request and the entire flow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to improve questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anypThe developers using the library should be able to disable certain fields in the JSON output. The list of disabled fields should be configurable. The flows responsible for logging in the JSON structure should be able to read the configuration and should not log those fields. This feature will be required in higher environments in case the team decides to disable certain fields in UAT and Prod.